# When can I access the Deep Roads in Dragon Age Awakening?

Tags: dragon-age-origins-awakening

I currently have access to and have cleared out the basement area in Vigil's Keep.

> Including locating, and subsequently decimating, Adria.

Sergeant Maverlies keeps saying that "The men are still clearing the rubble in the basement. They'll be finished soon." I've walked all the way back down a few times now, but the only options I have are to look around or return to the surface.

When will they be finished clearing the way? Is there a certain amount of time that has to pass, certain locations I need to visit, or certain quests I need to finish first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finish one of the quests in the main questline for Awakening, then come back.

Comment: So it can be *any* one of the other main quests?

Comment: Yes, any of the three quests in the main questline ("Shadows of Blackmarsh", "Righteous Path", "Last of the Legion").